# reactive forms - on Submit, check if there is at least one change in the form and only then call the API

Tags: angular6, angular7, angular-reactive-forms

What I want to achieve is something like this:

1. When the user clicks on Submit button, in the background I need to compare if the *state* of the form has changed, by *state* I mean if there is at least one change in the form and **only** then call the API/Server to save information.
2. If there are not any changes, just show a warning message to the user - "Hey you need to update something!"(console.log() is enough)
3. *I also need to handle this case when the user changes something in the field1, for example, from carrot to tasty carrot and then again back to a carrot(don't call API).

At the moment I have something like this - [code example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cepodu)

Is it possible to do that using *pristine/dirty/touched/untouched* properties?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using dirty check, RxFormBuilder provides a method `isDirty()` to check whether any updates are made in your formControl values.You just need to import FormGroupExtension and RxFormBuilder from @rxweb/reactive-form-validators package, you have to create a formgroup through RxFormBuilder . As you want to check onSubmit click whether any update is made of not, you can try using this method on your submit button click

```
 onSubmit() {
    let isDirty = (<FormGroupExtension>this.myForm1).isDirty();
    if(isDirty)
    {
       this.http.post(this.api, this.myForm1);
    }
    else{
      console.log("Hey you need to update something!");
    }
  }
```

Here is forked [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kc9pvt?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Interesting didn't know anything about https://github.com/rxweb/rxweb, thanks for sharing!