# How to find which FormGroup inside FormArray was changed by the user?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a reactive form with FormArray in it.

```
@Component({...})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input()
    items: Item[]

    itemsFormArray = new FormArray([]);
    form = new FormGroup({
      items: this.itemsFormArray
    });

    ngOnInit() {
        this.items.forEach(item => this.addRow(item));    
    }
    addItem(item: Item) {
        const doorFormGroup = new FormGroup({
            width: new FormControl(item.width),
            height: new FormControl(item.height),
        });
        this.itemsFormArray.push(doorFormGroup);
    }
}
```

I want to submit changes to the server by observing value changes. I can subscribe to `valueChanges` on form itself or on itemsFormArray, I'll be notified with whole array of data for each item.

How do I know which Item was changed by the user, or which FormGroup instance in `itemsFormArray`?

I know I can subscribe to each FormGroup in `itemsFormArray`, but it does not seems to me like a good solution. Is there any more effective way to know which item exactly was changed in an array and submit changes only for changed Item?

Comment: cannot you check `dirty` status ?

Comment: Why you think subscribing to all the formgroups is a bad solution? That's just what you need. Other solution may be more dirty. You could use distinctUntilChanged to check previous emission with the new one e see what changed exactly, but this is just more complicated and error prone

Comment: @kaosdev at first glance I thought that a lot of subscriptions will be created. But after thinking about it I think I should create a subscription to each FormControl, not just FormGroup. Because while I'm in process of posting data to the server user may change another attribute and I'll have a conflict when trying to apply changes to an object that this FormGroup represents. I'll post my solution in answers.

Comment: You should save your entire array in your POST/PUT if possible

Comment: @vladimirPrudnikov  You can check this example of dirtyCheck  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54673450/reactive-forms-on-submit-check-if-there-is-at-least-one-change-in-the-form-an

Comment: @kaosdev oh, for sure NO.

Comment: @MadhawaPriyashantha @UshmiDave the problem with dirty is that after submitting changes to the server I have to mark this FormGroup as pristine. What if user has edited another input in the same FormGroup in between request started and finished? I mark it as pristine while changes is waiting while `debounceTime` expires and next time observer receives changes this form group will already be marked as pristine, changes will not be saved.